# Embedded Felix, running inside android-app cant resolve org.osgi.framework

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix

i cant figure out why the following happens:

I am running an embedded apache felix from a small android application. I programmatically install 2 bundles after starting the framework, but both never enter the "resolved" state. Thereby the Bundle "MyBundle1" imports "MyBundle2".

This is what Logcat tells me:

```
05-17 20:21:56.514: ERROR/MainActivity(384): org.osgi.framework.BundleException:    
Unresolved constraint in bundle de.xy.MyBundle1 [1]: Unable to resolve 1.11: missing   
requirement [1.11] package; (package=de.xy.MyBundle2) [caused by: Unable to resolve 2.0: 
missing requirement [2.0] package; (&(package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0))]
```

I totally understand what the error-message says (well...org.osgi.framework in version 1.5+ cant be resolved) but i cant figure out why this happens. Why cant the framework resolve "himself"?! I tried to run the same felix.jar as standalone with the     adb shell    , and both bundles work. Ofcourse, the felix.jar is up to date (3.2)

Thanks for your advice!

Daniel

FelixSetup

```
    m_configMap = new StringMap(false);
    try {
        m_cache = File.createTempFile("felix-cache", null);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
    m_cache.delete();
    boolean mkdirs = m_cache.mkdirs();  // works (=true)
    m_activator = new HostActivator();  // implements BundleActivator 
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(m_activator);
    m_configMap.put(FelixConstants.LOG_LEVEL_PROP, "1");
    m_configMap.put(BundleCache.CACHE_ROOTDIR_PROP, ".");
    m_configMap.put(FelixConstants.SYSTEMBUNDLE_ACTIVATORS_PROP, list);
    m_configMap.put(FelixConstants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE, m_cache.getAbsolutePath()); 
    m_felix = new Felix(m_configMap);
    try {
        m_felix.start();
    } catch (BundleException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I dont know if it has something to do with the previous problems:

```
05-18 08:52:59.149: VERBOSE/out(363): Problem creating boot delegation class loader:      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-18 08:52:59.209: VERBOSE/out(363): ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement:  (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:A header cannot be an empty string.)

05-18 08:52:59.209: VERBOSE/out(363): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A header cannot be an empty string.
```

I install and start the bundles with

```
myBundle1= bundleContext.installBundle("file:/data/felix/MyBundle1.jar"); 
myBundle2= bundleContext.installBundle("file:/data/felix/MyBundle2.jar"); 

myBundle1.start();
```

they were previously dx'ed and moved to /data/felix with *adb push*.

The same code I used in the android-application also works inside a regular java console-app.

Comment: i forgot to mention: even if i remove the "version" from the import-package directive of both bundles, it cant be resolved

Comment: Can you show the code that sets up and starts the framework? Also, does your embedding code work on a 'regular' java?

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried it an created a console application, used the same code for starting the framework, the same bundles (felix.jar, MyBundle1.jar, MyBundle2.jar), and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you build up the framework looks okay to me. You could consider

- replacing the `FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES` by a list that is specific for Android, if your bundles will e.g. be using Activities), or
- not using a temp file, but point to some directory you know exists.

We have used 3.0.1 in the past successfully, and I do have the idea that the error message you posted has something to do with it. You could try that version of Felix, and if that works, you may have found a regression in Felix, which you can then report to users@felix.apache.org .

Comment: *replacing the FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES by a list that is specific for Android* , that helped - at last! thanks a lot.